# ¿Cómo agrupo datos en categorías numéricas consecutivas?

Tags: base-de-datos, r

Tengo un *df* del tipo

**`df1`**

```
df1 <- data.frame("ID_Sitio" = c("ES022", "ES023", "ES024", "ES022", "ES023", "ES024"),
              ID_Individuo = c("001", "002", "005", "011", "022", "055"),
              fecha = c("01-01-2001", "02-01-2001", "03-01-2001", "01-01-2001", "02-01-2001", "03-01-2001"),
              stringsAsFactors = F)


ID_Sitio     ID_Individuo    fecha           
ES022        001             01-01-2001
ES023        002             02-01-2001
ES024        005             03-01-2001
ES022        011             01-01-2001
ES023        022             02-01-2001
ES024        055             03-01-2001
```

Quiero crear un nueva variable que se llame `ID_Fecha`, que cuando `ID_sitio` y `fecha` sean iguales, les ponga 1, 2, 3, de tal manera que el resultado final sea

**`df2`**

```
ID_Sitio     ID_Individuo    fecha           ID_fecha          
ES022        001             01-01-2001       1 #Todos los 1 corresponderán al ES022, fecha 01-01-2001
ES023        002             02-01-2001       2  
ES024        005             03-01-2001       3
ES022        011             01-01-2001       1
ES023        022             02-01-2001       2
ES024        055             03-01-2001       3
```

¿Cómo lo hago? He visto que a lo mejor debería calcular el número de intervalos y la amplitud de los datos (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEv8NT46A4M), pero no sé cómo aplicarlo a cuando quiero hacer la agrupación por dos variables distintas. De momento lo único que he hecho es ordenar de manera ascendente la fecha y el ID_sitio...

Luego debo determinar cuántos individuos hay por categoría, pero creo que haciendo una tabla de frecuencias absolutas se resolvería.

Gracias nuevamente!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe otra forma un poco mas sencilla de hacerlo con `dplyr`, usando la función `group_indices()`

```
df1 <- data.frame("ID_Sitio" = c("ES022", "ES023", "ES024", "ES022", "ES023", "ES024"),
                  ID_Individuo = c("001", "002", "005", "011", "022", "055"),
                  fecha = c("01-01-2001", "02-01-2001", "03-01-2001", "01-01-2001", "02-01-2001", "03-01-2001"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)


library(dplyr)

df1$ID_Fecha<-df1%>%group_indices(ID_Sitio, fecha)
df1
  ID_Sitio ID_Individuo      fecha ID_Fecha
1    ES022          001 01-01-2001        1
2    ES023          002 02-01-2001        2
3    ES024          005 03-01-2001        3
4    ES022          011 01-01-2001        1
5    ES023          022 02-01-2001        2
6    ES024          055 03-01-2001        3
```

Answer (score 4):

Primero replicamos tus datos:

```
df1 <- data.frame("ID_Sitio" = c("ES022", "ES023", "ES024", "ES022", "ES023", "ES024"),
              ID_Individuo = c("001", "002", "005", "011", "022", "055"),
              fecha = c("01-01-2001", "02-01-2001", "03-01-2001", "01-01-2001", "02-01-2001", "03-01-2001"),
              stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Después creamos un data frame temporal que nos devuelva las combinaciones únicas de ID_Sitio y fecha

```
df1Work <- df1[!duplicated(df1[, c("ID_Sitio", "fecha")]), c("ID_Sitio", "fecha")]
```

Asignamos un valor único a cada unda de estas combinaciones:

```
df1Work <- data.frame(df1Work, ID_Fecha = c(1:dim(df1Work)[1]))
```

Lo juntamos con el data frame original:

```
df2 <- merge(df1, df1Work, by = intersect(names(df1), names(df1Work)), all.x = T)
```

Y tenemos el resultado:

```
df2
     ID_Sitio   fecha           ID_Individuo  ID_Fecha
1    ES022      01-01-2001      001           1
2    ES022      01-01-2001      011           1
3    ES023      02-01-2001      002           2
4    ES023      02-01-2001      022           2
5    ES024      03-01-2001      005           3
6    ES024      03-01-2001      055           3
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Javier! Funciona perfecto! Sólo una cosa más, no entiendo muy bien la línea del merge, pues nunca había usado el by=intersect(names(x), names(y)). Me podrías explicar por si acaso? Nuevamente muchas gracias!!!!!

Comment: La función merge(x, y, by = c("aa", "bb")) busca coincidencias entre las tablas x e y, en las columnas con nombre "aa" y "bb"; y une las filas de los data frame x e y en las que coinciden los valores en esas columnas.

La funcion intersect(a,b), siendo a y b vectores, devuelve aquellos valores que aparecen en ambos vectores.

Answer (score 4):

Usando `tidyverse` la solución es bastante sencilla y clara:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Generamos un tabla con los grupos y
# un id numérico para cada uno
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID_Sitio, fecha) %>% 
    summarize() %>%
    rowid_to_column("grupo") -> grupos

# Combinamos el df original con el de los grupos
df1 %>%
    left_join(grupos)

  ID_Sitio ID_Individuo      fecha grupo
1    ES022          001 01-01-2001     1
2    ES023          002 02-01-2001     2
3    ES024          005 03-01-2001     3
4    ES022          011 01-01-2001     1
5    ES023          022 02-01-2001     2
6    ES024          055 03-01-2001     3
```

Comment: Al generar la tabla con los grupos y un ID para c/u me sale el error "Error in quickdf(.data[names(cols)]) : length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE". A qué puede deberse?

Comment: Por que seguramente hayas cargado también `plyr` eso provoca varios conflictos, no uses `plyr` y `dplyr`  de forma combinada

Comment: de cada grupo he sacado las frecuencias y ahora debo tomar aquellos que tengan una frecuencia <=10 y redistribuirlos en cualquier otro grupo, de tal manera que todos tengan una freq >10. Tienes alguna sugerencia de cómo hacerlo? Había pensado df1$grupo2<-ifelse(freq<=10, grupo+1, grupo), pero el problema es que no siempre sumándole 1 a "grupo", tendré un grupo con freq>10...